How to create Horizontal swipe card, Right card swipe remove card and left swipe card index append in UIkit
class SwipeCardComponentVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var dataSource = ["Card 1", "Card 2", "Card 3", "Card 4", "Card 5"]  // Example data source
    var removedCards: [(card: String, indexPath: IndexPath)] = []  // To store removed cards for undo
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Configure the custom layout
        let layout = TinderLayout()
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:)))
        collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }
    
    // Collection view data source methods
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SwipeCardCell", for: indexPath) as! SwipeCardCell
        let color = ["DBA979","BACD92","9BB0C1","8E7AB5","80BCBD","C3E2C2","AFC8AD","D2E0FB"]
        cell.bgView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: String.getString(color[indexPath.row]))
        
        return cell
    }
    
    @objc func handlePanGesture(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = gesture.location(in: collectionView)
        guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: location),
              let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? SwipeCardCell else {
            return
        }
        
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: collectionView)
        cell.center.x += translation.x  // Horizontal movement
        gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: collectionView)
        
        if gesture.state == .ended {
            let threshold: CGFloat = 100  // Define threshold for swipe off
            let direction: CGFloat = translation.x > 0 ? 1 : -1
            if abs(translation.x) > threshold {
                if direction < 0 {  // Swipe left to remove
                    swipeLeftAction(cell, indexPath)
                } else {  // Swipe right to append
                    swipeRightAction(cell, indexPath)
                }
            } else {
                // Reset the card's position if not swiped far enough
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                    cell.center = self.collectionView.center
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func swipeLeftAction(_ cell: SwipeCardCell, _ indexPath: IndexPath) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            cell.center.x -= 1000  // Swipe off to the left
        }, completion: { _ in
            // Store the removed card for potential undo
            self.removedCards.append((self.dataSource[indexPath.item], indexPath))
            // Remove the card from the data source and collection view
            self.dataSource.remove(at: indexPath.item)
            self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
        })
    }
    
    func swipeRightAction(_ cell: SwipeCardCell, _ indexPath: IndexPath) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            cell.center.x = self.collectionView.center.x  // Reset the position
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}


//MARK:-----SetCollectionViewFlowLayout----


class TinderLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    private let itemSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 600)  // Set the size of each card
    private let interItemSpacing: CGFloat = 10  // Space between stacked cards
    
    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()
    }

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return .zero }
        return collectionView.bounds.size
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return nil }
        
        var attributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []
        
        let numberOfItems = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
        
        // Keep the original order to ensure the first item is on top
        for index in 0..<numberOfItems {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
            if let attr = layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath) {
                attributes.append(attr)
            }
        }
        
        return attributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return nil }
        
        let attr = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
        
        attr.size = itemSize
        let center = collectionView.center
        attr.center = CGPoint(x: center.x, y: center.y)
        
        // Adjust position for overlapping effect
        attr.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -CGFloat(indexPath.item) * interItemSpacing)
        
        return attr
    }
}

not working properly please help

Please review [ask]. You need to give us a better description of what you're trying to do, and what's not working as you expect.

Video Link :-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oEnNpXxWT44saiqALF_4fX9k5ehr0KDh/view?usp=sharing
I want to make it like this in Swift.
